# Reading data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, database

I'm planning to use XML for database purpose. Only thing I was able to do is read whole XML file. I want to be able to read only some data and I don't know how to do that.

Here is a simple XML

```
<Books>
 <Book>
  <Title>Animals</Title>
  <Author>J. Anderson</Author>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Title>Car</Title>
  <Author>L. Sawer</Author>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

I'm interested in app where output is gonna be

```
Books:
Animals
Cars

Authors:
J. Anderson
L. Sawer
```

I'm just want to learn how read specific data from XML not whole file.

[SOLVED]
I have used Linq to XML

Comment: Is the file too big to be read completely? You *can* use `XmlReader` to read just bits, but it's a *lot* simpler to read the lot in via LINQ to XML and then just *select* the bits you want...

Comment: file is not too big about 5-10 KB

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I don't think you can "legally" load only part of an XML file, since then it would be malformed (there would be a missing closing element somewhere).

Using LINQ-to-XML, you can do `var doc = XDocument.Load("yourfilepath")`. From there its just a matter of querying the data you want, say like this:

```
var authors = doc.Root.Elements().Select( x => x.Element("Author") );
```

HTH.

**EDIT:**

Okay, just to make this a better sample, try this (with @JWL_'s suggested improvement):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args )  {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "XMLFile1.xml" );
            var authors = doc.Descendants( "Author" );
            foreach ( var author in authors ) {
                Console.WriteLine( author.Value );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to adjust the path in `XDocument.Load()` to point to your XML file, but the rest should work. Ask questions about which parts you don't understand.

Comment: I think doc.Decendants("Author") is a better alternative.

Comment: @JWL_ Probably. To be honest, I just typed in the first thing that came to mind. Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but I'm confused what to do next. When I use Console.WriteLine(authors); it shows some nonsense. I do not realy understand how it works. Can you put here more complete code ? Thanks

Comment: Well, `authors` would be an `IEnumerable` collection of `XElement`s, so yeah, `Console.WriteLine()` would just give you the default `.ToString()` of the underlying `object`.

Comment: I used            var authors = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => x.Element("Author"));
            foreach (var author in authors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(author);
            }

Comment: @Safiron Added full sample. See answer.

Comment: How can I achieve the same in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268245/how-to-extract-every-occurence-of-tags-in-an-xml-file

Comment: What if I have a root `<statement>` and then a child `<statement>`? How do I get the child `<statement>` value? I tried this: `var statement = x1.Element("statement").Descendants("statement");` but that didn't work :/

Answer (score 12):

as per @Jon Skeet 's comment, you should use a XmlReader only if your file is very big. Here's how to use it.
Assuming you have a Book class

```
public class Book {
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Author {get; set;}
}
```

you can read the XML file line by line with a small memory footprint, like this:

```
public static class XmlHelper {
    public static IEnumerable<Book> StreamBooks(string uri) {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri)) {
            string title = null;
            string author = null;

            reader.MoveToContent();
            while (reader.Read()) {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                    && reader.Name == "Book") {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                            reader.Name == "Title") {
                            title = reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                            reader.Name == "Author") {
                            author =reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    yield return new Book() {Title = title, Author = author};
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
string uri = @"c:\test.xml"; // your big XML file

foreach (var book in XmlHelper.StreamBooks(uri)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Title, Author: {0}, {1}", book.Title, book.Author);  
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly how I thought it could be done. My database is not big no more than 50 records

Comment: well, then I would not really use this approach. As you can see it's a lot of code to do what Linq.Xml would do in 2 or 3 lines of code. Take a look at @Tieson T.'s answer for instance.

Comment: yeah its a good way but Linq is better for my purpose

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use XPathNavigator:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XPathNavigator navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

string books = GetStringValues("Books: ", navigator, "//Book/Title");
string authors = GetStringValues("Authors: ", navigator, "//Book/Author");
```

..

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the string values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="description">The description.</param>
/// <param name="navigator">The navigator.</param>
/// <param name="xpath">The xpath.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string GetStringValues(string description,
                                      XPathNavigator navigator, string xpath) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(description);
    XPathNodeIterator bookNodesIterator = navigator.Select(xpath);
    while (bookNodesIterator.MoveNext())
       sb.Append(string.Format("{0} ", bookNodesIterator.Current.Value));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430357/how-to-get-xml-web-service-response-in-c-sharp) regarding the xml response?

Answer (score 1):

Try GetElementsByTagName method of XMLDocument class to read specific data or LoadXml method to read all data to xml document.