# visual studio 2010 limiting published files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am able to successfully publish my application online. however, since I use 3rd party dlls, what I noticed is that each time I publish, all the files versions are updated. Which means whenever users launch my app and there is an update, the update procedure has to download those same dlls over again although they have not changed. Only my app .exe has changed. Is there a way I could publish my app in a way that only the .exe file gets updated?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: [How to: Manage Updates for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx)

Comment: Yes I am aware of this but I can't exclude any of the 3rd party dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I am not shure but I'll think you can specify it in your project settings. (Project -> Properties). There are also the update settings located. (I'll think the last tab)

Comment: Well if I exclude the dlls then the app crashes when run.

Comment: hmm what about using an own update mechanism? There you can place a xml file on your update server where you describe wich file should be updated / downloaded. The rest is just parsing xml. Should not be that hard to do

Comment: that would seem adequate.... but beyond my abilities to implement. I was wondering if there was nothing within the visual studio environment that would allow/limit the update files.

Comment: it's not realy hard to implement. Just place an xml file on your server that contains the files you want to update and the version of each file. Than you just have to write a few lines of code to read the xml file and download the files. For reading a xml file look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml