# Getting XML elements textboxes from search string

Tags: c#, xml

I've got an XML file which has multiple entries, each looking like this:

```
-<CRQ>
 <ID>CRQ000000003314</ID>
 <Status>1</Status>
 <Summary>complete</Summary>
 <Service>Server</Service>
 <Impact>3000</Impact>
 <Risk>2</Risk>
 <Urgency>4000</Urgency>
 <Class>4000</Class>
 <Environment>1000</Environment>
 <Trigger/>
 <TriggerID>CP_00</TriggerID>
 <Coordinator>user name</Coordinator>
 <Desc>ticket description.</Desc>
</CRQ>
```

I have a string in a C# app which matches the id, eg CRQ000000003314. How would I be able to load the XML and then return the elements underneath the id (status summary etc) into separate text boxes when this string is matched on an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

var element = xmlDocument
            .Descendants("CRQ")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x.Element("ID") == "CRQ000000003314");

if(element != null)
{
    var status = (string)element.Element("Status");
    // get other values and display them in the textbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You can use Linq to XML: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Or you can use XMLReader:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader

IT is just the usual XML parsing with C#:

[Reading data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my way to do it :

```
//Added to set up the sample
var xml = "<root><CRQ><ID>CRQ000000003314</ID><Status>1</Status><Summary>complete</Summary><Service>Server</Service> <Impact>3000</Impact><Risk>2</Risk><Urgency>4000</Urgency><Class>4000</Class><Environment>1000</Environment><Trigger/><TriggerID>CP_00</TriggerID><Coordinator>user name</Coordinator><Desc>ticket description.</Desc></CRQ></root>";
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

//Coded Solution
var value = (from el in root.Elements("CRQ") where el.Element("ID").Value == "CRQ000000003314" select el).FirstOrDefault();

//Testing output
foreach(XElement el in value.Elements()){
    Console.WriteLine("Element Name: {0} = {1}",el.Name, el.Value);
}
```