# Parsing XML from string

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I'm sure this is very simple..

I have this as a string:

```
<OnTheRoadQuote xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OTRAPI.Services.Models">
<BasicPrice>15595.8333</BasicPrice>
<CO2>93</CO2>
<Dealer>Audi</Dealer>
<DeliveryCost>524.9900</DeliveryCost>
<DiscountPrice>14348.166636</DiscountPrice>
<DiscountSum>1247.666664</DiscountSum>
<Discounts>
<Discount>
<DiscountApplication>Percentage</DiscountApplication>
<DiscountDescription>Dealer Discount on Vehicle and Options %</DiscountDescription>
<DiscountID>Discount1</DiscountID>
<DiscountType>VehicleAndOptions</DiscountType>
<DiscountValue>8</DiscountValue>
</Discount>
</Discounts>
<OTR>17902.7879632</OTR>
</OnTheRoadQuote>
```

How do I read the value of the OTR node?

I've got an XmlReader but not sure how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Reading data from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml)

Comment: Why have you not googled this? There are countless articles on how to read data from XML in .NET

Comment: In fairness, the related questions focus on using `XmlDocument` and/or `XDocument`.  He's asking specifically how to load a string into an `XmlReader`

Answer (score 2):

Using XmlReader, and fixing a typo in your root element (missing space before the second `xmlns`):

```
string xml = @"<OnTheRoadQuote xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OTRAPI.Services.Models"">
  <BasicPrice>15595.8333</BasicPrice>
  <CO2>93</CO2>
  <Dealer>Audi</Dealer>
  <DeliveryCost>524.9900</DeliveryCost>
  <DiscountPrice>14348.166636</DiscountPrice>
  <DiscountSum>1247.666664</DiscountSum>
  <Discounts>
    <Discount>
        <DiscountApplication>Percentage</DiscountApplication>
        <DiscountDescription>Dealer Discount on Vehicle and Options %</DiscountDescription>
        <DiscountID>Discount1</DiscountID>
        <DiscountType>VehicleAndOptions</DiscountType>
        <DiscountValue>8</DiscountValue>
    </Discount>
  </Discounts>
  <OTR>17902.7879632</OTR>
</OnTheRoadQuote>";

string otrValue = "";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml))) // use a StringReader to load the XML string into an XmlReader
{
   reader.ReadToFollowing("OTR"); // move the reader to OTR
   reader.ReadStartElement(); // consume the start element
   otrValue = reader.Value; // store the value in the otrValue string.
}
```

Keep in mind that XmlReader is **forward only**, meaning that you can't navigate it backwards through the XML data to read, for example, `Discounts`, once you've pushed it to the `OTR` node.  If you want to do that, you should look into using `XmlDocument` or (preferably) `XDocument`.  However, if all you need to do is get the OTR value, this should be the most efficient (time and space) way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

With less code, you can use LINQ to XML and load an XElement with the xml or a file. There are also other options.

```
XElement element = XElement.Load(....);
var node = element.Element("OTR");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx