# how to configure and read a object from webconfig c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

i'm having a few throubles resolving an issue. I have to read data from webconfig file

```
<AmountsList>
  <Amount>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Value>20</Value>
    <Operator>Vodafone</Operator>
  </Amount>
  <Amount>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Value>30</Value>
    <Operator>Vodafone</Operator>
  </Amount>
</AmountList>
```

I've already look up for a solution but i coulnd't find anything that work as requested, and i'm still a noob in webservices.

My Problem is in setting up webconfig file with the data. I know that in a normal situation this shouldn't be in this file, but this is a request.

Comment: As you pointed out, the web.config file should store settings which control how your website works. Therefore you could create a XML-file and store it in The App_Data folder. Please see this post on how to retrieve data in the XML-format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to load the web.config file as a pure XML file and get required information from there. You can use `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` classes for this task.

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load("web.config");
```

Comment: Thanks, i've already solve it using a string to setup de data and decoding throught it, but this was also a workaround

Answer (score 2):

Check out custom configuration sections - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

You can then add a custom section to the app config, which you can then read / write to accordingly.

Comment: i had already tried it, but was unsuccessful. i solve it adding a string and decoding it to my object. thanks anyway