# LINQ to XML can't get element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to parse a tiny xml return from a web service using LINQ to XML. The XML looks like so:

```
<ns:ResponseTest xmlns:ns="http://websvc.tst.com">
    <ns:return>true</ns:return>
</ns:ResponseTest>
```

And looking around online I found this that should read in the first value with the specified name:

```
var returnValue = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "return");
```

But it's always coming up as null. I also tried using the namespace in the name (when I hover over the name (above: "return") it tells me I can use {namespace}name to provide a namespace) so it was "{ns}return". However that also didn't return anything.

How can I retrieve the return value from the above xml?

EDIT: I also tried the solution here [Reading data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/reading-data-from-xml) and the same thing happened. I couldn't get it to find the specified elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://websvc.tst.com";
var returnValue = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants(ns + "return").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LocalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the  unqualified part of the name

```
var returnValue = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants()
                           .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.LocalName == "return");
```